# Convert string to particular date format getting nil in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, nsdateformatter

I am getting date in string format from server. So I am trying to formatting to particular format.

But it is getting nil.

```
"07September16 4:09 am", This I want to format like Sep 07 2016
```

I am doing it with following code

```
dateLabel.text = model().formatStringToDate(dateString: date)
    
func formatStringToDate(dateString: String) -> String {
    let dateStr = dateString
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d yyyy"
    let formattedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)
    print("formattedDate \(formattedDate)")
    //I have to return formatted string here
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work;

```
// create `Date` from date string
let dateStr = "07September16 4:09 am"
let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterGet.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") 
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "ddMMMMyy h:mm a"
let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: dateStr)

// convert back Date to string as Sep 07 2016
let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "MMM dd yyyy"
print(dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date!))
```

Comment: This is wrong. `hh` is for 01-12. What you need is `h` 1-12. You need also to set the locale to `"en_US_POSIX"` before setting the `dateFormat` property when parsing a fixed date format. This might crash the app if the device 24 hour settings is set to 24h

Comment: Also OP should not choose how the date will be displayed to the user. OP should use `dateStyle` instead of `dateFormat` and use the current locale to display the date localized respecting the user device's locale and settings.

Comment: `dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium`. If none of the styles fit OP purpose he can also use dateFormatter method `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` => `dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyyMMMdd")
`

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateString = "07September16 4:09 am"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ddMMMyy h:mm a"
let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd yyyy"
print("Dateobj: \(dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!))")
```

Comment: This is wrong. `hh` is for 01-12. What you need is `h` 1-12. You need also to set the locale to `"en_US_POSIX"` before setting the `dateFormat` property when parsing a fixed date format. This might crash the app if the device 24 hour settings is set to 24h

Comment: yes , let me change. But still person cannot get same time due to locale difference

Comment: i have printed it, its serving the purpose.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: **if you're working with fixed-format dates, you should first set the locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed format. In most cases the best locale to choose is "en_US_POSIX", a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences. "en_US_POSIX" is also invariant in time (if the US, at some point in the future, changes the way it formats dates, "en_US" will change to reflect the new behaviour, but "en_US_POSIX" will not)**

Answer (score 0):

First you must get date from your string with current format like`

```
let dateStr = dateString
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ddMMMMyy h:mm a"
let formattedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)!
print("formattedDate \(formattedDate)")
```

After getting the date you can get date string in which format you want just change the format`

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd YYYY"
let convertedDateString = dateFormatter.string(from: formattedDate)
```